# Cant connect MySQL database to my spring project (despite all post i have read)

Tags: java, mysql, spring

i'am building a small APP, with google  api and spring boot, and i need to connect mysql db to my project.

First : all my package are in same places (to avoid this kind of issues TT)
So i first try with the doc exemple ( https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) by cloning the project
and  its return me : Failed to obtain JDBC Connection.

I try with my own app and i get this :
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in  + Failed to obtain JDBC Connection too.

```
application.properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8181/testuser
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

dependencies :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.devoteam.presales</groupId>
<artifactId>testspringsecu</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>testspringsecu</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.27.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>js-cookie</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev493-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Entity :

```
package com.devoteam.presales.testspringsecu;


import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
public class UsersDevo {


private Integer ID;
private String email;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String service;


public Integer getId() {
    return ID;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(String service) {
    this.service = service;
}
}
```

Repository :

```
package com.devoteam.presales.testspringsecu;

import com.devoteam.presales.testspringsecu.UsersDevo;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepo extends CrudRepository<UsersDevo, Long> {

}
```

test controller :

```
package com.devoteam.presales.testspringsecu;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller

@RequestMapping(path = "/demo")
public class TestController   {
@Autowired
UsersRepo usersRepo;

@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<UsersDevo> getAllUsers() {
    return usersRepo.findAll();
}

}
```

main

```
package com.devoteam.presales.testspringsecu;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.*;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class TestspringsecuApplication {


@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Model model, Principal principal) throws 
JSONException {
    OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) 
principal;

    return principal;
}


@GetMapping("/user")
public ModelAndView method() {
    System.out.println("icila");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + "/");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(TestspringsecuApplication.class, args);

  }

}
```

I also try a bunch of annotation.

EDIT :  i fixe the issue witht the doc exemple with :spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8181/testuser?serverTimezone=EST5EDT
but i still have : rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
with my app

Comment: Could you post the `SpringBootServletInitializer` class?

Comment: "testuser" sounds like a *user* name.  Is it also the name of the *database* to which you're trying to connect?  Because that's what's expected where that appears in your JDBC URL.

Comment: And is your mysql server indeed running on the local host, and serving port 8181?

Comment: And is the database password for user root really "root", and / or have you specified a valid *database* username and password in your actual configuration?

Comment: testuser is the name of my DB,  and yes my server is running on localhost 8181

Comment: i try to connect with intellij to my db and its work with localhost:8181/testuser root root

Comment: What version of Connector/J are you using?  You are specifying the name of the driver class provided by version 8, but that's different from the name that was appropriate in earlier versions.  And is Connector/J in your classpath?  Is there, by any chance, more than one version in your classpath?

Comment: are you talking about mysql-connector-java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did IT ( after looooog investigation).

And the answer ( for noob like me ) is that your entity must be exactly the same as your table.
my mistake was to forget the  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO) on private Integer ID.
SPring could be painfull some times ... ( often..)

and  dont forget ?serverTimezone=EST5EDT after database url.

i hope saving some hours to someone.